# Laravel 5.2 Dingo/api resources group

Tags: php, api, laravel, dingo-api

As the title mentions, I am trying to figure out how to make a resource group by dingo.

As it explains with laravel, the correct way to make a resource group in route is:

```
Route::resource('item', 'Api\ItemController');
```

is it similar with the dingo/api? can I just say:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function($api){
    $api->resources('item','App\Http\Controllers\Api\ItemController');
});
```

When executing this way, i get a type error:

> Argument 1 passed to Dingo\Api\Routing\Router::resources() must be of the type array, string given

Does this mean that I have to make an array of all the calls that I need and then pass it to the `resources` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo there. The actual method is `resource` not `resources`

```
$api->version('v1', function($api){
    $api->resource('item','App\Http\Controllers\Api\ItemController');
});
```

Comment: @Nabim Oh shoot, i missed that. That actually got it to work! thankyou for your quick answer!